# Ionic Runtime Error ( A network error)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

Hello I have this problem and i don't know how to solve it. 
`A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.` I read `Install cordova-plugin-whitelist` might fix the problem but the same error still occurs. Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you have a CORS-related browser plugin active in your web-browser ?

Comment: how do I know ??

Comment: Depending on your web browser, you might have plugins/extensions installed. Go through the configuration of your browser and check if you have any installed. In my experience, having a CORS-related extension in Chrome activated using Firebase and not correctly configured might trigger the issue you experience.

Comment: ohh i checked there is none

Comment: Does this occurs on mobile or browser environment ? In your browser, did you check the 'Developer Tools', in particular the Network and  Console tabs ?

Comment: i had to enable the sign in method from the firebase console under authentication. but thank you so much for answering

Comment: Alright, good to hear you had it work. Would you mind answering your own question and accepting it, so that users can find the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to enable the sign in method from the firebase console under authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Under Ionic +4 and firebase +5 import firebase as

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Importing firebase as the following will create the Runtime Error ( A network error)

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

Don't forget to rebuild the project